# Impossible to cut object into two halves

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier, bisect

I simply want to cut the pumpkin model in half using the other plane, two get two pieces that fit together when I 3d-print them. But for some reason I cant figure out how to do it. I tried simply using a boolean difference but that always left me with just one side of the pumpkin, not two. Have tried other tools like knife project as well but there must be some easier way to do this that I havnt figured out... please help.
[image]

Comment: Duplicate it and do the operation twice - once for each half, just flip the normals of the plane for the second one.  The plane is non-manifold so it's eliminating everything on the side that it sees as "inside" the plane.

Answer (score 1):

For a boolean to work, you need a manifold mesh with some thickness. A plane or a circle is non-manifold and zero thickness.

Add a Solidify modifier to your circle and set the thickness to something small (like 0.01mm). Or <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to validate.

Then your boolean modifier should be able to split your pumpkin where you put the circle.